# How to read Desktop Notifications in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

My goal is to write a powershell script that runs every n seconds, reads through any notifications on my Windows 10 home edition desktop that have been sent since the last run, and then send me emails if certain notifications have occurred. I can handle the scripting and task scheduler piece, I'm just having trouble finding the powershell way to check my Desktop notification queue.

This is the only post I could dig up on the subject and it remains unanswered https://powershell.org/forums/topic/get-notifications/. Most other posts I find are focused on generating notifications from powershell and not reading them. I also haven't been able to find anything that looks correct in the API docs either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like there is an [API for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener), which you _might_ be able to [access via standard C#](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) (then via PowerShell).  Seems like a lot of work - what specifically are you trying to do?  Maybe there is an easier way to do _that_.